# SEO - What element should i use for a heading?

Tags: html, seo

For SEO purposes, what tag should I use for my comments heading? The heading tag for the comments contains the Heading of the page with the added word: Comments. Should this be a H2 or H3 or something else? Thanks

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micro-optimizations and tweaks for SEO purposes are mostly unnecessary nowadays, just make your page semantic to make the search engines interpret it better.

If you used a [`H1`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html) heading for the title of your article (which I think is the best choice), then use a [`H2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h2.html) heading for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You should use H2 as H1 is used by Search Engines for Headings in the page.

Answer (score 1):

The heading tags `<h1>`, `<h2>`, create a document outline based not only on their number but also their position relative to sectioning.  That is, `<body><h1>` is the header for the document.  You can use `<h2>`, or if comments are in their own `<section>` you could still use `<h1>`.  You should not skip headings order (i.e. do not use `<h3>`).

Note that the lack of `<h1>`/heading in `<section>` makes it an untitled section.  You can see how search engines / headless browsers will outline your page using this tool: http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

In summary I would recommend

```
<h1>Document heading</h1>
<section>
    <h1>Content Heading</h1>
    Content
    <section>
        <h1>Comments Heading</h1>
        Comments
    </section>
</section>
```

It makes sense to me for comments about the content to be a subsection of the content itself.